# flutter Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

// I am having this issues when trying to retrieve the address from firebase

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

updating the dart tools and the flutter tools worked for me